# HTML CSS Issues in implementing nested ordering which includes numbers, alphabets and roman numbers

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-counter

I have a requirment to implement a nested ordered structured html page very similar like this. Most of the part is done but I got stuck at 1 place in ordering of number. Please suggest.
Below is the required structure and my code.

```
1.Main Line 111111111 
    1.1 Sub Line 111111111 
        a.aaaaaaaaaaa
        b.bbbbbbbbbbb

2.Main Line 22222222
    2.1 Sub Line 111111111 
        a.aaaaaaaaaaa
        b.bbbbbbbbbbb   
    2.2 Sub Line 22222222 
        a.aaaaaaaaaaa 
            i.moreeeeee
            ii.moreeeeee
        b.bbbbbbbbbbb 
            i.moreeeeee
            ii.moreeeeee
```

But getting some overlapped numbers as shown in image:
[image]
Please suggest where I am doing wrong?

Here in my code:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: item;
}

.sub-num-list>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.sub-num-list>ol>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.sub-albhabatical-list>li {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.sub-roman-list>li {
  list-style-type: lower-roman;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout__wrapper">

  <ol>

    <li>Main Line 111111111
      <ol class="sub-num-list">
        <li>Sub Line 111111111
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb</li>
          </ol>
        </li>

      </ol>
    </li>

    <li>Main Line 22222222
      <ol class="sub-num-list">
        <li>Sub Line 111111111
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Sub Line 22222222
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa
              <ol class="sub-roman-list">
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb
              <ol class="sub-roman-list">
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Sub Line 111111111
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using an `ol`, therefore, it's adding a number by default. You could remove it with that `.sub-num-list { list-style: none; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were wrong in the use of your `:before` and the list `counter` CSS property. Also you probably got lost in CSS selectors and ended up with undesired effects.

I fixed it for you, hopefully this is what you were looking for

```css
li {
  display: block
}

.main-num-list, .sub-num-list {
  counter-reset: item
}

.main-num-list>li:before,
.sub-num-list>li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}

.sub-albhabatical-list {
  counter-reset: letter;
}

.sub-albhabatical-list > li:before {
  content: counter(letter, lower-alpha) ". ";
  counter-increment: letter;
}

.sub-roman-list {
  counter-reset: roman;
}

.sub-roman-list > li:before {
  content: counter(letter, lower-roman) ". ";
  counter-increment: roman;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout__wrapper">

  <ol class="main-num-list">

    <li>Main Line 111111111
      <ol class="sub-num-list">
        <li>Sub Line 111111111
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb</li>
          </ol>
        </li>

      </ol>
    </li>

    <li>Main Line 22222222
      <ol class="sub-num-list">
        <li>Sub Line 111111111
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Sub Line 22222222
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa
              <ol class="sub-roman-list">
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb
              <ol class="sub-roman-list">
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
                <li>moreeeeee</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Sub Line 111111111
          <ol class="sub-albhabatical-list">
            <li>aaaaaaaaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbbbbbbbb</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

You can find some more informations in similar questions about [list counter formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1) and [nested different list-style-type counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410573/how-to-combine-numbers-and-letters-in-ordered-list)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this style in your style section.

```
.sub-num-list{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

It'll remove overlapping of numbers